# Is there a .NET default AND common values reference

Tags: .net, math, default-value

I already know there's [Default Values Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) as well as it's [relatives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dhd7f2x%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

However, it'd be nice to have a **printable chart** which shows:

- default values table
- Min/Max for built-in numerics (including TimeSpan and DateTime)
- Other useful math numbers (e.g. [PI = 3.14159265358979323846](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pi.aspx))
- Maybe some 2^N = ...

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: "useful" is subjective. You'd be amazed how often I don't use Pi. And how rarely it changes. And 2^N - any you don't recognise on-sight are probably too long to compare accurately at a glance...

Comment: Why do you need to know the values of these constants? The whole point of them existing is so that you don't need to know them.

Comment: Of course, you could print out your own favourites... Maybe include a few of your [top 10 guids](http://secretgeek.net/hotguids/)...

Comment: @marc: i'm amazed at how often my co-workers put their own PI value in our codebase. also, i'll definitely slap some guids on there too ;)

Comment: @R.: because the hardware spec that I'm looking at doesn't say "with a max value of Int16.MaxValue". (I need to know what the values are to use the constants in code.)

Comment: @jberger Data Type Ranges: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Magnus: thank you for the reference.  I ended up rolling out my own.

Answer (score 0):

it exists for C++ see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hwaceh6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) .
In the math class of .NET as you ask there are two: E and PI, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.aspx).

Comment: Thank you.  However, I was particularly interested in .NET (not C++).  Also, I know of `System.Math` class; however, it still doesn't address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[xlsx](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-sEsn2syMHLVDRfM3dsM3pqVUk) (source)

[pdf](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-sEsn2syMHLZktSbUg2a01mMTg) (for printing)